# WIX: Choose different image files for different DPI setting?

Tags: image, wix, dpi

A known issue with WIX is that e.g. the side-banner image when looking good in 100% DPI setting scales badly when the system is at 125%, 150% or whatever setting.

I tried changing the side-banner image to be 150% the size to see if it scales down better then up, but it didn't. On 150% it now looks great, but terrible still on 125% and 100%.

Can the wix script be fiddled with so that it makes the installer choose different image files with different sizes depending on the DPI setting or in some other way determine the size of the dialog and pick the most appropriately sized side-banner image?

That way I would cover 100%, 125% and 150% which are commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "wix script".  WiX is declarative XML that transforms into declarative Windows Installer table data.  There is nothing imperative / procedural / scripting about it.

All UI limitations are in the underlying Windows Installer and not related to WiX at all. I'm aware of many limitations but I've never heard of the one you mention.  I can't reproduce it on my installs.  Can you provide screen shots of what you are seeing?

It is possible to have multiple image controls and use control conditions to make them mutually exclusive.  But I'm not convinced this is needed in this situation.  Also if UI polish is important to you it's probably time to consider rolling an external UI handler instead of using native UI.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it not being a script that is "run" when the setup is running, so it's a matter of "defining" the WIX XML to allow for different images depending on the DPI setting on the target system.

Comment: In the image below I illustrate the problem.

I have built two setups, one where the image is the size expected on a 100% DPI system (B), and it looks correct with 100% DPI setting but when running in 150% DPI setting, it gets poorly stretched.

(A) on the other hand, the image is made in a size that is correct when the setting is set to 150% DPI, but then when having 100% DPI setting this gets poorly scaled down.

The image can be found here: http://postimg.org/image/gd6wut3hp

Comment: Why is your dialog image 740x468?  It should be 493x312 assuming you are using the UI Extension.

Comment: According to that image, it's 493x312 which makes it look OK in 100% DPI but bad when stretched @ 150% DPI.

Changing the image to be 740x469 (which is 150% size-up) makes it look ok @ 150%DPI but then looks bad when scaling down @ 100% DPI.

That's the thing - would like to have the two images and get the installer to choose either the 492x312 when having 100% DPI or take 740x468 when having 150% DPI.

Comment: Can you post your images so I can attempt to reproduce? I always use a 492x312 image and I've never seen this issue.

Comment: I made a mockup with a diamond and tried to change my DPI settings and reboot to take effect.  My laptop decided to give me a BCD boot error and not I have to recover. I probably won't have time to go further on this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

So yes, there will be some scaling when different DPI settings are used.  But I think the results can be decent when properly designed and implemented graphics are used.  I looked your postimg.org link and your examples were blown up even further and showed some weird dithering in the lines.

I think diagonal lines are a pretty extreme example but here is how it can look:
Small Settings:
[image: Small]
Large Settings:
[image: Large]

Finally, here is the source image that was used to build the installer:
[image]

Comment: That does look good, but why? Is it only the fact that you have chosen a 45 degree rotation which makes the scaling "kind". 

http://s3.postimg.org/b2bg0vmcz/shapes.jpg

The image here was just an example, it's actually concerning a product logo which is more elaborated and does incorporate a non 45 degree shape in red with black outline.

Would the conclusion be to go with an external UI handler as mentioned earlier?

Comment: I chose a red and black diamond because that's what you showed in your sample.  Your sample seemed to not be very clean in the first place and that you then blew it up at the DPI level and then again at the screen capture / scale level.  Personally I'd stay with a standard WiX UI scheme and just talk to a graphics artist about cleaning up the logo to scale better. I'm sure he would have some tricks.  Otherwise yes, an external UI handler rendering scalable vector graphics would be your prettiest choice.  But it's not something I'd bother doing for a run of the mill installer.